# Scraping etoro with python

Tags: python, css, selenium, web-scraping, finance

I'm trying to use Selenium to automatically connect to my etoro account and get some figures from my portfolio. I work on Google Colab and from now, here is what I have:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

wd = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wd.get("https://www.etoro.com/fr/login")

username = "username@mail.com"
password = "password"

elementID = wd.find_element_by_css_selector("input[automation-id='login-sts-username-input']")
elementID.send_keys(username)
elementID = wd.find_element_by_id("password")
elementID.send_keys(password)
```

However, I have this error message

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[automation-id='login-sts-username-input']"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.77)
```

I have tried to change and use find_element_by_class, by_xpath, etc but I couldn't find how to do it.

Could you give me a hand here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works:-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@id='username']")
```

Comment: Switched to VScode and works perfectly with your code. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to run with headless mode, removing that argument fixes this. In any case, that is where your problem lies.

I suspect that in headless browser mode we may be encountering some kind of bot detection. If you NEED to run in headless perhaps we can find a way around that.

Comment: Couldn't make it work on colab without the "options.add_argument('--headless')". I switched to VScode and used @itronic1990 code and it works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, Selenium removed some method in version 4.3.0, so your code shall be modified as:

```
...
elementID = wd.find_element("xpath",".//*[@id='username']")
...
elementID = wd.find_element("id","password")
...
```

See [AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72754651/attributeerror-webdriver-object-has-no-attribute-find-element-by-xpath)