# AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

test = webdriver.Chrome()
test.get('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeYUmAYYZNtbU8t8MRxwJo-        d1zkmSaEHodJXs78RzoG0yFY2w/viewform')

time.sleep(5)

Name = 'kuch bhi'
last = test.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
last.send_keys(Name)
```

When i execute the code, I get an error that says,

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Selenium just removed that method in version `4.3.0`. See the CHANGES: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a4995e2c096239b42c373f26498a6c9bb4f2b3e7/py/CHANGES

```
Selenium 4.3.0
* Deprecated find_element_by_* and find_elements_by_* are now removed (#10712)
* Deprecated Opera support has been removed (#10630)
* Fully upgraded from python 2x to 3.7 syntax and features (#10647)
* Added a devtools version fallback mechanism to look for an older version when mismatch occurs (#10749)
* Better support for co-operative multi inheritance by utilising super() throughout
* Improved type hints throughout
```

You now need to use:

```py
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
```

In your example, you would use:

```py
last = test.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
```

For improved reliability, you should consider using `WebDriverWait` in combination with `element_to_be_clickable`.

Comment: Thanks, It worked but where did you learn to do it the new way? I have just seen the documentation, it mentions the old methods

Comment: I'm on the Selenium Technical Leadership Committee, where I spend time with the team online, and there are video calls occasionally. https://twitter.com/SeleniumBase/status/1448685115610214406?s=20&t=tx5-m9d_ea6PHpgsHEZXJA (I'm in the loop when it comes to updates.)

Comment: Oh! Please if possible in any way, just keep compatibility with older versions and/or include a depreciation warning in advance...

Comment: There was a deprecation warning before that (assuming it wasn't being ignored). And I was not in favor of this decision by the higher leadership of the Selenium committee to remove compatibility with older scripts. I created [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) to do things a bit differently, and older methods don't get removed. Scripts from 2016 still work with the latest version.

Comment: How would someone go about printing all xpath IDs. for example before you could do this. ```ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id]')
         for ii in ids:
             print(ii.get_attribute('id'))```

Comment: @Swannie For finding multiple elements and making a list: ``driver.find_elements(by=by, value=selector)``

Comment: 145 k views - not such a bad outcome for an IMHO awfully bad decision

Answer (score 27):

You can now use:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//<your xpath>')
```

Comment: that's actually the perfect way to do it using XPath in selenium above 4 version

Answer (score 21):

As per the [changelogs of Selenium 4.3.0](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a4995e2c096239b42c373f26498a6c9bb4f2b3e7/py/CHANGES):

```
Selenium 4.3.0
* Deprecated find_element_by_* and find_elements_by_* are now removed (#10712)
```

and as per the [merge](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/10712) the 16 replaced strings are as follows:

```
.find_element_by_class_name(
.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 

.find_element_by_css_selector(
.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 

.find_element_by_id(
.find_element(By.ID, 

.find_element_by_link_text(
.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 

.find_element_by_name(
.find_element(By.NAME, 

.find_element_by_partial_link_text(
.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 

.find_element_by_tag_name(
.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 

.find_element_by_xpath(
.find_element(By.XPATH, 

.find_elements_by_class_name(
.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 

.find_elements_by_css_selector(
.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 

.find_elements_by_id(
.find_elements(By.ID, 

.find_elements_by_link_text(
.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, 

.find_elements_by_name(
.find_elements(By.NAME, 

.find_elements_by_partial_link_text(
.find_elements(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 

.find_elements_by_tag_name(
.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 

.find_elements_by_xpath(
.find_elements(By.XPATH,
```

---

### This usecase

So effectively you have to replace the line of code:

```
last = test.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
```

as:

```
last = test.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
```

---

### Note

You will also need to import `By` as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score -1):

e = driver.find_element(by.By.XPATH,'//label[@analytics-event="All matches"]')
from selenium.webdriver.common import by