# python textbox NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, textbox, nosuchelementexception

I got this error NoSuchElementException when I run the following script.

`driver.find_element("xpath", "//*[@id='lastAttemptYear']").click().send_keys("2022")`

The original element has shown below.

`<input type="text" size="5" maxlength="4" id="lastAttemptYear" name="lastAttemptYear" onkeyup="moveOnMax(this,'lastAttemptMonth')" value="2022" autocomplete="off">`

What should I do? thanks!

Comment: Please show all your code. And if possible including the link to the page you are working on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72754651/attributeerror-webdriver-object-has-no-attribute-find-element-by-xpath)!

I have to do this first!

```
frame = driver.find_element("xpath", '//frame[@name="main"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
pass1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "lastAttemptYear")
```