# New to Jupyter Notebook. Can someone tell me pls?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jupyter-notebook

Trying to scrape an ecommerce website. It has rows of buttons/images which keeps loading more products as you scroll. On which element or element-id should the code perform Click() so as to retrieve product name, price, description ....attributes

Getting an error on

```
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='productTitle']")
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
```

Can anyone please tell me with an example? Thank you so much

Thanks,
Sunil

Comment: You want `driver.findElement(By.XPATH(...))`.  It's up to YOU to figure out which buttons you need to click.  We can't see the web site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find\_element\_by\_xpath'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72754651/attributeerror-webdriver-object-has-no-attribute-find-element-by-xpath)

Comment: Does it work on Jupyter notebook? Can you pls tell me few samples for findElement?