# Selenium does not put data

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://sanctum.pl/register.html")
driver.maximize_window()
#Lokalizatory
x = "Josh123"
y= "josh123@gmail.com"

input_first_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/span/form/div[2]/fieldset/div/input").send_keys(x)
input_last_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/span/form/div[1]/fieldset/div/input").send_keys(y)
```

I was trying to put some data into browse forms but it is not working any suggestions?
I also get this in terminal

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50932/devtools/browser/f9638d1b-c140-4146-9d53-f5534ea6c850       
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Python\Selenium\skrypt.py", line 19, in <module>
    input_first_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/span/form/div[2]/fieldset/div/input").send_keys(x)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
PS E:\Python\Selenium> [6268:18388:0306/204146.997:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(218)] [20:41:46.997] 
USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Urz╣dzenie do│╣czonennection: Urz╣dzenie do│╣czone do komputera nie dzia│a. (0x1F)
```

Comment: What line is throwing that error? My guess is that there's something in your setup/installs that isn't correct.

Comment: Your code looks fine but your XPaths are really, really brittle. Using Copy XPath from the browser typically generates long XPaths like this. Using XPaths that start at `/html`, have a lot of levels, or have a lot of indices is generally a bad practice. I would give you a new XPath but I can't access the site. If you will put the relevant HTML for the first/last name fields, I'll give you a new locator.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the full error message as text, properly formatted.

Comment: I tried also shorter xpath for login //*[@id="__BVID__126"] and email //*[@id="__BVID__149"] but it didn't help, also tried on other pages and still data is not pushed

Comment: Dublicate? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65497385/20443541

Comment: @kaliiiiiiiii I saw this topic but this error isn't my main problem, as said there you can just ignore it and your data should be pushed - but in my case it is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
```

...implies that the version of *Selenium* client you are using has no attribute as *`find_element_by_xpath`* as [`find_element_by_*` commands are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69875984/7429447)

---

### Solution

Instead of:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_value")
```

you have to use:

```
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "xpath_value")
```

---

### This usecase

Your effective line of code will be:

```
x = "Josh123"
y= "josh123@gmail.com"
input_first_name = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//html/body/div[1]/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/span/form/div[2]/fieldset/div/input").send_keys(x)
input_last_name = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//html/body/div[1]/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/span/form/div[1]/fieldset/div/input").send_keys(y)
```

---

### tl; dr

[AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75489249/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

```py
input_first_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html...")
```

Isn't a valid syntax for Selenium with **Python**.

It should be:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options, service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://sanctum.pl/register.html")
driver.maximize_window()
#Lokalizatory
x = "Josh123"
y= "josh123@gmail.com"

input_first_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/span/form/div[2]/fieldset/div/input").send_keys(x)
input_last_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/section[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/span/form/div[1]/fieldset/div/input").send_keys(y)
```

[reference](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)