# Get text from a span element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, syntax-error, findelement

It is a dynamic span. I want to get the number that keeps changing. In this case it would be **436**

Code trials:

```
valorliquido = navegador.find_element_by_css_selector("span[class="woocommerce-summary__item-value"]")
```

Got:

```
valorliquido = navegador.find_element_by_css_selector("span[class="woocommerce-summary__item-value"]")
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Snapshot of the HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have used double-quotes to wrap the class name of the CSS selector and also to wrap the whole selector string. This causes a syntax error because the interpreter is not able to distinguish between the two sets of double-quotes.

You can fix this by using single quotes

```
valorliquido = navegador.find_element_by_css_selector('span[class="woocommerce-summary__item-value"]')
```

Or escaping the double quotes so they have no effect

```
valorliquido = navegador.find_element_by_css_selector("span[class=\"woocommerce-summary__item-value\"]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care of a couple of things:

- If you pass the locator value within double quotes i.e. `"..."` you have to use the single quotes for the attribute values as `'...'`
- With [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) [find_element_by_* commands are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69875984/7429447) and you have to use the [following syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75489249/7429447):

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

  find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css_selector_value")
  ```

---

### Solution

Youe effective line of code will be:

```
valorliquido = navegador.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.woocommerce-summary__item-value span[data-wp-component='Text']")
```

To print the text **436**:

```
print(navegador.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.woocommerce-summary__item-value span[data-wp-component='Text']").text)
```