# Select an element of an drop-down list

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I want to select an option of an form using a Selenium to automate an task of download. Here're the steps of what i need to do:

1st. - Click into a bar of the "Formulário"
[image]

2st. - Select the option "Relatório de Emissão Tokio ID1000013"
[image]

I'm using the follow code to make theses steps, but in the end (in this part describe above) the code doesn't run.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

servico = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

navegador = webdriver.Chrome(service=servico)
navegador.implicitly_wait(10)
navegador.get('http://site.com.br')
navegador.implicitly_wait(10)
navegador.find_element('xpath', "//a[@id='linkMenu_1500']").click()
navegador.implicitly_wait(10)
navegador.find_element('xpath', "//a[@id='menu_1501']").click()
navegador.implicitly_wait(10)
navegador.find_element('xpath', "//a[@id='subMenu1000006']").click()
navegador.implicitly_wait(10)
element = navegador.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='id_formulario']")
```

But the code above returns this:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 14
     10 navegador.implicitly_wait(10)
     11 # Selecione a opção "Relatório de Emissão Tokio" no formulário
     12 #lect = Select(navegador.find_element_by_id("id_formulario"))
     13 #elect.select_by_value("1000013")
---> 14 element = navegador.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='id_formulario']")

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
```

Please, how can I do this tasks using Selenium?

*Obs.:* The page source code of this bar is:

```
<select class="form-control fichaCampo campoform" id="id_formulario" name="id_formulario" eng_idcoluna="1000835" title="Formulário" eng-possui-condicao="True" eng-executa-condicao-invisivel="False" eng-preenche-campos="dv_periodo,cd_tp_apolice,cd_status,nm_descricao" eng-index-linha="0" eng-sql-datatype="int" data-toggle="popover">
<option>
</option>
    <option value="1000010">Acumulo&nbsp;por&nbsp;tomadores&nbsp;com&nbsp;Grupo&nbsp;Econômico&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ID1000010
</option>
    <option value="592">Followup&nbsp;de&nbsp;Tomadores&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ID0000592
</option>
    <option value="1000009">Gerencial&nbsp;-&nbsp;Cotação/Propostas/Estudos&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ID1000009
</option>
    <option value="322">Gerencial&nbsp;-&nbsp;Produção&nbsp;por&nbsp;Periodo&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ID0000322
</option>
    <option value="475">Relatório&nbsp;de&nbsp;Acúmulo&nbsp;Geral&nbsp;da&nbsp;Exposição&nbsp;do&nbsp;Tomador&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ID0000475
</option>
    <option value="492">Relatório&nbsp;de&nbsp;Acúmulo&nbsp;Geral&nbsp;da&nbsp;Exposição&nbsp;do&nbsp;Tomador&nbsp;-&nbsp;CCG&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ID0000492
</option>
    <option value="1000013">Relatório&nbsp;de&nbsp;Emissão&nbsp;Tokio&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ID1000013
</option>
    <option value="366">Relatório&nbsp;de&nbsp;Emissões&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ID0000366
</option>
    <option value="562">Relatório&nbsp;Geral&nbsp;de&nbsp;Tomadores&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ID0000562
</option>
    <option value="1000007">Relatório&nbsp;Gerencie&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ID1000007
</option></select>
```

Comment: Check this  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72754667/7598774

Answer (score 0):

The method you're using no longer works
You should use this

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, value="YOUR XPATH HERE")
```

Comment: This method didn't work. The code returns "NoSuchElementException" in navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//input[@id='id_formulario']") line

Comment: @VictorSoares Make sure you're entering the correct XPATH, alternatively you could try Adding a WebDriverWait to ensure that the element is present on the page before clicking on it

Comment: XFranko, still doesn't work. I put the correct XPATH in the code: navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, value="//select[@id='id_formulario']") and I also put an WebDriverWait like !navegador.implicitly_wait(10)" before execute the method find by XPATH. ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)