# web scraping wikipedia using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Initialize the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Edge()

WIKI = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India"
driver.get(WIKI)

# Find the <div> element with class "mw-page-container"
page_container = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="mw-page-container"]')

# Find all elements of interest inside the page container
elements = page_container.find_elements(by='css selector', value='h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li')

# Save the content to a text file
with open('site_content.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for element in elements:
        tag_name = element.tag_name
        if tag_name.startswith('h'):  # Check if it's a heading
            file.write(f"-----### {element.text} ###-----\n")
        elif tag_name == 'p':  # Check if it's a paragraph
            file.write(element.text + '\n')
        elif tag_name in ['ul', 'ol']:  # Check if it's an unordered/ordered list
            list_items = element.find_elements(by='tag name', value='li')
            for item in list_items:
                file.write(f"- {item.text}\n")

# Don't forget to close the webdriver
driver.quit()

file_path = 'site_content.txt'

print("Content saved to 'site_content.txt'")
```

So I was randomly doing web scraping and wanted to extract all the useful data from a Wikipedia page into txt file but wasn't able to remove that login /sign up button from top actually GPT did it I was just telling what to do but bro tried everything and failed

the terminal showed this :

```
page_container = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="mw-page-container"]')
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
```

Comment: Did you try page_container = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="mw-page-container"]')?

Comment: Why not use Wikipedia's API for this? Example: `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=India&format=json` API docs: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Get_the_contents_of_a_page

Answer (score 1):

```
page_container = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="mw-page-container"]')
```

`find_element_by_xpath` this is no more used starting selenium `v4.3.0`.Change above line to:

```
page_container = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="mw-page-container"]')
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_element_by_xpath` was removed. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72754667/7058266)

For your action, you would now need to use:

`driver.find_element('xpath', '//*[@class="mw-page-container"]')`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="mw-page-container"]')
```